# why is form input undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, events, setstate

I am new in JS and maybe ask a stupid question. But I need your help to understand. I have a form.

```js
const Form = () => {
  const[form, setForm] = useState({
      
      username: ''

  })

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setForm({
        ...form,
        [event.target.name]: event.target.value
   
    })
  }

  const handleSubmit= (event) => {
    console.log(form.username)
    event.preventDefault()
  }
    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <div>Username</div>
          <input
            name='username'
            type='text'
            placeholder='name'
            value={form.username} 
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <button type='submit'>Ok</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }


export default Form
```

Why console.log value is undefined? When I change handleChange like

```js
const handleChange = (event) => {
        setForm({
          username: event.target.value
       
        })
      }
```

everything is ok.

Comment: `[event.target.name]: event.target.value` is a way I would do it, expecially if form have multiple inputs. Can't see any problem with your code. It's just a bit odd that in updating state - you are destructuring object which have only one key-value pair.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code looks good and works good. Have to create [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-forest-bd5jn) to be absolutely sure. Have a look for yourself :)

Comment: This should have been a comment.

Comment: thank you very much. I have understood, the problem was in *...form*. It works if the form has multiple inputs.

Comment: You are welcome. With your code, form should work even if it have only one input. Who knows what was the issue.. Anyway, I am glad that you have it (issue) resolved.